# Library Drag and Drop no working for all users

Tags: sharepoint-online, drag-and-drop

Need help in troubleshooting possible causes for why a user is unable to drag and drop documents into a SharePoint Online library.  They have contribute rights to the site and contribute rights to the library.  They can manually upload items, edit items and delete items but are unable to drag and drop files.  When they attempt to do so, the curser changes into a circle with a line through it.  I'm able to drag and drop files to the library, but I'm also a System Admin.  The user is accessing SharePoint via Chrome and has M365 suite installed and updated.  Suggestions for troubleshooting much appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can check to narrow down this issue:

1. Upgrade to the l[atest version of Chrome](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/dragging-files-using-web-browser).
2. Switch to another browser and see if it works.
3. Check if the user has run Chrome as Administrator. If yes, uncheck “Run this program as an administrator” via `Properties > Compatibility`.

   Reference: [Google Chrome's drag drop feature stopped working.](https://superuser.com/questions/994283/google-chromes-drag-drop-feature-stopped-working)